# Deprecating and Sunsetting endpoints in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

It's very hard to find documentation in Django Rest Framework for deprecation decorators. It seems the first few pages in google list Django's changelog and the various functionality they are deprecating, rather than how to deprecate endpoints in your own app.

I have an API that I'm trying to develop inline with API evolution principals. As such, one of my endpoints needs to be marked as sunset/end of life/deprecated.

Can I do this with Django decorators? The idea would be to list a date when this endpoint will no longer be available. I do not have API version numbers (API evolution), so there is no API version to mark.

```
# Here's my old action that doesn't follow REST standards which I'd like to deprecate    
@action(url_path="filter", methods=["post"], detail=False)
def get_filtered(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    .....

    return filtered_queryset
```

The closets solution I've found is below.. but I think it's not the "Django Rest way"

```
@action(url_path="filter", methods=["post"], detail=False)
def get_filtered(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = filtered_queryset
    response['Warning'] = 'This endpoint is deprecated and will be removed on April 1st 2023'

    return response
```

Can anyone offer better suggestions to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question has been going unanswered for a few months but I was searching for a similar solution and surprised that I didn't find anything etiher. What I think could work is a simple decorator like the following:

```py
import functools
import logging

from django.http import HttpResponse

logger = logging.getLogger("my.logger")


def deprecated(deprecation_date=None, end_of_life_date=None):
    """
    Returns a decorator which informs requester that the decorated endpoint has been deprecated.
    """

    def decorator_deprecated(func):
        """Amend the request with information that the endpoint has been deprecated and when it will be removed"""

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_deprecated(*args, **kwargs):
            # do something before handling the request, could e.g. issue a django signal
            logger.warning("Deprecated endpoint %s called", func.__name__)

            response: HttpResponse = func(*args, **kwargs)
            
            # amend the response with deprecation information
            if isinstance(response, HttpResponse):
                response.headers["X-Deprecated"] = ""
                if deprecation_date:
                    response.headers["X-Deprecation-Date"] = deprecation_date
                if end_of_life_date:
                    response.headers["X-End-Of-Life-Date"] = deprecation_date
            return response

        return wrapper_deprecated

    return decorator_deprecated
```

This example of a decorator can then be applied to the endpoint you named like:

```py
@deprecated(deprecation_date="2023-01-06")
@action(url_path="filter", methods=["post"], detail=False)
def get_filtered(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    .....

    return filtered_queryset
```

The decorator will add a `X-Deprecated` header to the response and will optionally also add some information from when on the endpoint was deprecated and when it will be finally removed (`end_of_life_date`). Obviously, this information could also be provided within the response body but it's usually better to not mess with the response as this could potentially affect some clients that expect a certain response.

It might also be good to keep track of whether or not the deprecated endpoint is still used by some 1st or 3rd party, hence the log. It might also make sense to issue e.g. a [django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/#sending-signals) when a deprecated endpoint is used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm going to be trying it this week and will accept the answer if it does what we expect.